# Why is simplejson encoder for html escaping with \\u0026 instead of &amp; letting an XSS happen?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, simplejson

I am trying to automatically html escape strings going into json objects. simplejson has [JSONEncoderForHTML](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/simplejson/encoder.py#L374-376) which is supposed to do exactly that. This is how it escapes html:

```
chunk = chunk.replace('&', '\\u0026')
chunk = chunk.replace('<', '\\u003c')
chunk = chunk.replace('>', '\\u003e')
```

#### 1) Why is it using these codes instead of the html encoding that [cgi.escape](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/cgi.py) uses?

Which is:

```
chunk = chunk.replace('&', '&amp;')
chunk = chunk.replace('<', '&lt;')
chunk = chunk.replace('>', '&gt;')
```

Each of them state:

simplejson: *To embed JSON content in, say, a script tag on a web page, the characters &, < and > should be escaped. **They cannot be escaped with the usual entities (e.g. &) because they are not expanded within  tags.***

cgi.escape: *Replace special characters "&", "<" and ">" to HTML-safe sequences.*

#### 2) What does the part in bold really mean here?

Other than not understanding the differences here, the core of my problem is that the simplejson method lets an XSS happen, but if I go in its html encoder and change the replace calls to the ones of cgi.escape, no XSS.

Given this input `{'label': 'XSS HERE"><script>alert(1)</script>'}`

Here is the output with simplejson.encoder.JSONEncoderForHTML:

```
{"label": "XSS HERE\"\u003e\u003cScript\u003eAlert(1);\u003c/Script\u003e"}
```

Here is the output with simplejson.encoder.JSONEncoderForHTML and changing the codes in `replace` to `&amp;`, etc. as indicated earlier:

```
{"label": "XSS HERE\"&gt;&lt;Script&gt;Alert(1);&lt;/Script&gt;"}
```

It used used for autocompletion from a .js script (not between  in a html file) with this:

```
return $('<a/>').attr('href', result.url)
        .append($('<img>').attr('src', imageurl)
            .addClass(image_class)
            .after($('<span/>')
            .addClass(label_class).text(result.label)));
```

`result.label` is the value of the key `'label'`.

#### 3) So why do I get a javascript alert displaying 1 with the simplejson method, but not with the cgi.escape escaping?

Are codes like `\\u003c` decoded and treated as `<` characters?

To give more context, this is so I don't have to do this in every JSON handler of my web app and potentially forget to escape something:

```
response = {'A': Escape(a), 'B': Escape(b)} # with many more variables here
return json.dumps(response)
```

#### 4) Is there an alternative way of automatically escape for html what will be returned in json?

A recursive walk of the object like [tornado.escape.recursive_unicode](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/_modules/tornado/escape.html) but with escaping instead?
Something else?

Update: This will alert, so why would one escape using this method?

```
<div id="alert">a</div>
$("#alert").html("XSS HERE\"\u003e\u003cScript\u003ealert(1);\u003c/Script\u003e");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AcLYd/

Answer (score 0):

JSONEncoderForHTML makes JSON safe for embedding in a `<script>` tag, it does not do what you want it to do and there's no reasonable way to do that with this library.

Comment: When I replaced the escaping with chunk.replace('&', '&amp;'), etc. the output was escaped the way I needed. I understand now that this was not the goal of this encoder, but is the change of escaping I just mentionned not a "reasonable way" for my purpose (which is escaping every key and value for html/js)? What would you suggest as an alternative way of doing what I am looking for (other than calling cgi.escape(myvalue) everywhere on my object's values)?

Comment: Well, the whole premise of what you want to do is misguided. The solution is to call `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: You are saying that escaping server-side is misguided. OWASP states that "Both reflected and stored XSS can be addressed by performing the appropriate validation and escaping on the server-side.". Also my templating engine escapes by default, so including server data in HTML or js is safe. Escaping html in json the same way makes it so everything is escaped server-side, not 50%. Easier to manage. I don't have to use .html() from templates and .text() from js handling json. .html() is not the only insecure write. See http://open.bekk.no/owasp-top-10-for-javascript-a2-cross-site-scripting-xss

Comment: Yes, trying to use a sledgehammer to indiscriminately HTML escape keys and values in an entire JSON document is indeed misguided. The two best solutions are to use the appropriate functions in the client to guarantee that XSS isn't possible, or generate the values in the document with the correct escaping (before any sort of encoding is attempted).

Comment: So auto-escaping data that goes in html or javascript from a template engine is common but auto-escaping data that goes in javascript from a json response is misguided? Why is it misguided?

Comment: The template engine can do the right sort of escaping (and in some cases, no escaping at all) based on context. There's no context when you are indiscriminately escaping everything an entire structured document. It's far easier (trivial in fact) to correctly prevent XSS by working at the level of DOM and not HTML fragments anyway, so I don't really understand why you really want to justify doing it this way. It's not "easier to manage".